# The "Run Inference" doesn't work in Maestro edition

Tags: topbraid-composer

I downloaded the maestro edition and was following the starter guide with the Person ontology tutorial. It has been good until i tried the inference example. I clicked "Inference->Run Inferences", in the 'inferences' views, it's empty. nothing inferred. Also with SparQL query, it didn't infer. Should I first configure some reasoners?

```
SELECT ?subject ?object
WHERE {
    ?subject person:hasChild ?object
}
```

With the inference configurations, it doesn't show any Williams's children.
The message log is below.
[image]